# Toggle and untoggle three buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have three buttons and I want to toggle between them. How can I add and remove the toggle and untoggle classes to have to toggle appropriately. 
Right now, both buttons can be selected/toggled on. There should only be one button toggled at a time but I also want to be able to deselect/untoggle all of the buttons. So that I have 
an option of not toggling the buttons on.

Here's the buttons in my view:

```
<div id="drawing">
  <div style="margin-top: 12px; padding-left: 8px; margin-bottom: 8px">
    <button class="small-button" onclick="Drawing.AngleClick()" data-val-btnname="Angle" style="width: 70px; height: 20px;"><span>@Culture.GetString("Angle")</span></button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 12px; padding-left: 8px;">
    <button class="small-button" onclick="Drawing.PointClick()" data-val-btnname="Point" style="width: 70px; height: 20px;"><span style="font-size:10px !important">@Culture.GetString("Point")</span></button>
    <button class="small-button" data-val-btnname="ClearAll" style="width: 70px;" onclick="Drawing.Delete()"><span>@Culture.GetString("ClearAll")</span></button>
</div>  
</div>
```

Here's the js function so far for one of the buttons (I have the same if statement in my other button):

```
AngleClick: function () {
    var button = $('body').find("button[data-val-btnname='Angle']");

    if (button.hasClass('small-toggled-button')) {
        button.removeClass('small-toggled-button').addClass('small-button');
    } else {
        button.removeClass('small-button').addClass('small-toggled-button');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy method for toggling buttons. Run the snippet to see it work. I simplified your HTML *only for the sake of shortening the example*--I'm not suggesting you change it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#drawing button").click(function(e) {
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    if (!isActive) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #555555;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing">
  <button class="small-button">Angle</button>
  <button class="small-button">Point</button>
  <button class="small-button">ClearAll</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm okay but I would like to reclick on the button to untoggle it rather than have a separate button for it. Is that alright?

Comment: @KalaJ No problem--I updated the code/snippet to do that.

Comment: Wait, n00b question but the buttons don't have an "active" class attached to them yet it's being applied, how?

Comment: @KalaJ The line `$(this).addClass('active');` is adding the `active` class to whatever button is clicked.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be getting called (I put it into init)